# Return only innermost promise's catch and handle others

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following scenario:

```
savePicture(newPicture, fileData){
    return compressionUtil.makePictureAndThumbnail(newPicture).then((data) => {
        let writeBig = fsUtil.writeFileToDisk(pictureFileName, data[0])
        let writeSmall = fsUtil.writeFileToDisk(thumbnailFileName, data[1])

        return Promise.all([writeBig, writeSmall]).then(() => {
            let picToSave = {
                uploaderUsername: fileData.username,
                directory: fileDirectory,
                fileName: fileName,
                tags: fileData.tags,
                description: fileData.description,
                droneTaken: fileData.droneTaken,
                isGenuine: isGenuine,
                metadata: metadata
            }
            return Picture.create(picToSave)
        })
    })
}
```

What I am looking to do is handle possible promise rejections of `compressionUtil.makePictureAndThumbnail()` and `Promise.all([writeBig, writeSmall])` like so

```
savePicture(newPicture, fileData){
    return compressionUtil.makePictureAndThumbnail(newPicture).then((data) => {
        let writeBig = fsUtil.writeFileToDisk(pictureFileName, data[0])
        let writeSmall = fsUtil.writeFileToDisk(thumbnailFileName, data[1])

        return Promise.all([writeBig, writeSmall]).then(() => {
            let picToSave = {
                uploaderUsername: fileData.username,
                directory: fileDirectory,
                fileName: fileName,
                tags: fileData.tags,
                description: fileData.description,
                droneTaken: fileData.droneTaken,
                isGenuine: isGenuine,
                metadata: metadata
            }
            return Picture.create(picToSave)
        }).catch((err)=>{/*Handle promise.all error here*/})
    }).catch((err)=>{/*Handle makePictureAndThumbnail error here*/})
}
```

but at the same time make `savePicture()` return only `Picture.create()` 's promise .then() and .catch().

What I have thought about is wrapping it all in a giant new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{}) but probably that's a terrible practice.

Input on that is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you should try to present a MWE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make your question more accessible and increase your chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wrapping it all in a giant new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{}) is probably a terrible practice.

Yes [indeed it is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

To handle rejections only from the promise and not the `then` fulfillment callback, you can [use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572):

```
savePicture(newPicture, fileData){
    return compressionUtil.makePictureAndThumbnail(newPicture).then((data) => {
        …
        return …
    }, err => {
//   ^ no `catch`
        /* Handle makePictureAndThumbnail error here */
    });
}
```

Similarly,

```
return Promise.all([writeBig, writeSmall]).then(() => {
    let picToSave = { … }
    return Picture.create(picToSave);
}).catch(err => {
    /* Handle all errors from writeBig, writeSmall and create */
});
```

```
return Promise.all([writeBig, writeSmall]).then(() => {
    let picToSave = { … }
    return Picture.create(picToSave).catch(err => {
        /* Handle errors from create */
    });
}, err => {
    /* Handle all errors from writeBig and writeSmall */
});
```